# How to continuously update pyplot figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, graphing

I am trying to create a gui that will continuously update a matplotlib plot as data is collected.  I would like the plot to keep the past 5 data points and have some empty space in front of the most recent data point.

Here is an extremely simplified version of my script that illustrates where my problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time

pylab.ion()

x1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
x2 = [5,6,7,8,9,10]

y1 = [5,6,7,8,7,8]
y2 =[8,7,6,5,4,3]

rate = 1
timer = 0
count = 0

while count <2:
    if timer == 0:
        pylab.plot(x1,y1)
        pylab.show()
        timer += rate
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        pylab.plot(x2,y2)
        pylab.draw()
        timer += rate
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

I have already tried using show(block=False) and a few other things. Is there anyway to force the figure to stay open while the code continues and a command I can use to update it? Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `plt.pause` instead of `time.sleep` take make sure the gui updates properly.

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence worked for me..

- ion() - interactive on
- show()
- plot()

Do update graph here like
- plot()
- draw() - instead of show()