# Pylab only updating after raw_input call

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to continuously read from a file and plot using `matplotlib` as a way to create a bit of an animation. Here is the working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time

print "start"

pylab.ion() # Unfortunately, will still need to run pylab.show() all the time
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlim((0,128))
ax.set_ylim((0,128))

#Initialize the circle object to a silly location
f1 = pylab.Circle((60,68), radius=2, fc='y')
ax.add_patch(f1)
pylab.show()

# Start the animation
for i in range(0,1000):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        f1.center = 30, 30
    else:
        f1.center = 40, 40
    pylab.show()
    raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
    print("Updating")
    #time.sleep(2) # This is going to be used later
```

Now, I want to replace the user input with a sleep timer:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time

print "start"

pylab.ion() # Unfortunately, will still need to run pylab.show() all the time
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlim((0,128))
ax.set_ylim((0,128))

#Initialize the circle object to a silly location
f1 = pylab.Circle((60,68), radius=2, fc='y')
ax.add_patch(f1)
pylab.show()

# Start the animation
for i in range(0,1000):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        f1.center = 30, 30
    else:
        f1.center = 40, 40
    pylab.show()
    #raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
    print("Updating")
    time.sleep(2) # This is going to be used later
```

But this code doesn't work! It sleeps, but nothing is updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `time.sleep(2)` with `pylab.pause(2)` as indicated in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242189/how-to-continuously-update-pyplot-figure).